# How to include normals in my obj export

Tags: modeling, normals, obj

I was making a game in Java and lwjgl.This type of game development needs Vertex positions and normals to render a model , along with texture coordinates and indices. Now i exported a simple obj file from blender and opened it in Notepad++.The file has information for Vertex position , and Texture Coordinates but i don't have normal data which causes an error , so the question is How to export Normal data in OBJ file

PS : i have enables **Write Normals** in export settings , but there is no normal data in the file

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem was i was using a very simple model , a cubelike model , which didnot have any normals but the 90 deg so i tried to export the monkey model and it worked